# Best implemenation of saving and accessing numeric and Dates data

Tags: android, serialization, dictionary, sharedpreferences

I'm currently making my first Android app. The app uses a counter to store certain data which I then need to save somewhere so that I can access it later (after closing and reopening app) and on different fragment views.

I was thinking of using SharedPreferences, but I had two main concerns.

1. Would I be able to store Dates as the key for the integers? I need to be able to create a special view where the integers are sorted by their date so that the user can view the count for each day.
2. Would I be able to have multiple layers inside a SharedPreference? Sort of like a map inside a map. The reason being is that I may want differentiate by the time in a day as well in the future.

The number entries need to be sorted by date so I was thinking of creating a Map to store the total amount of numbers per day and saving that to a File via serialization. However, I may add a feature in the future where I would add another layer of a Map as follows:

```
Map<Date,Map<Time, int>>
```

Which would be a better way of implementing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Preferences are great for simple things like settings- things that have straightforward boolean, string, or numeric values and the data is key-value format.  If you need more than that, you're better off writing them to a file.  Either come up with your own format or write it out in JSON.

Comment: So would my idea of using serialization on a Map be a good method? Never used JSON